# My sql select query during long updates on the same table. Junk or old data?

Tags: mysql, select, update

What happens when select query happens simultaneously during long updates. Will I be seeing a junk data or the old data before update.

Answer (score 1):

It is controlled by Transaction Isolation Levels in MySQL. Default Transaction Islation Level is Repeatable Read. With this you will see the old data until it is committed.